# Mathematica's Tables and Modifications in Octave?

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, octave

How can I do Mathematica-style

```
a = Table[2^(2 k) + 1, {k, 1, 3}]
Last[a], First[a]
Append[a,3]
```

in Octave?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do this as

```
2 .^ (2 * [1:3]) + 1
```

Here, `[1:3]` stands for the vector `[1,2,3]` and `.^` denotes entry-wise exponentiation.

**Added** after question was edited: 
These are rather basic questions. I think you need to spend some time learning Octave; for instance, read through [this tutorial](http://homepages.nyu.edu/~kpl2/dsts6/octaveTutorial.html).

Comment: Thank you, very useful tutorial.